# HTML - use of the onbeforesubmit attribute

Tags: html, forms, submit

I recently found a form event attribute called `onbeforesubmit` which processes a given function/request before the form is actually submitted.

While I found it to be useful, seems strange to me almost no 'official' documentation is found about this event attribute, with a vague reference to a Microsoft web page and some forums. No w3schools or w3 reference about it (not as far as I have looked up).

Is it a very old/deprecated event attribute or maybe an experimental one? I have tested it with Google Chrome so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its an old attribute . Its work can be replaced by onsubmit. you can write code in the manner of you want the execution and cal it on onsubmit

Comment: Is this event triggered before or after validation?

Answer (score 2):

I have met [Phalcon](http://www.phalconphp.com/en/) forms with this event defined. Found [this documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_4_5_X/Component_Reference/en-US/html/chap-Component_Reference-Common_Ajax_attributes.html#sect-Component_Reference-Events_and_JavaScript_interactions-onsubmit) of `onbeforesubmit`. It says:

> The `onbeforesubmit` event attribute invokes the event listener before an Ajax request is sent. The request is canceled if the event listener defined for the `onbeforesubmit` event returns `false`.

Comment: That's JBOSS and appears to be for dealing with generating Ajax requests from XML. It doesn't appear to have anything to do with any of the tags on the question.

Comment: I stumbled upon `onbeforesubmit` while deciphering my way through a Phalcon tutorial, where the fremework produces the following tag `<form action="/invo/register" onbeforesubmit="return false" ... >`. And as @julio-meca-hansen, I have a hard time figuring out what this event does for my form.